# Expect: 100-continue with the nginx proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

Nginx does not pass Expect 100-continue header to the proxy_pass server.
How to pass all incoming request to the proxy server?

Comment: Did it worked? we have the same issue but dont seems working with the below solution. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
proxy_set_header Expect $http_expect;
```